# How to bend tube so it's ends fit given positions?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to bend the tube, so it fits the end caps.

[image]

The bent tube is made from the straight one at the right. I wish would tube reach the end caps correctly, but failing.

In another attempt, I used a "by-eye" approach.

First I adjusted limits and moved the bent tube appropriately:

[image]

Then I applied the modifier and removed the unneeded faces:

[image]

This works, but I'd like to use a more precise solution. Can anyone think of a way to do this more precisely?

Comment: I cant awnser your question. But I can suggest a more accurate workflow for precision modeling which may exclude this problem, taught here in the bearing tutorial (using the spin tool): http://www.rab3d.com/tut_blender.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the precise awnser to your question using "curves".

I suggest you use the "spin tool" to get the desired "precise" effect and control.

Add a circle.

[image]

In front view.

Go to edit mode.

Move the circle to which point you want.

[image]

Press spin. (It wil spin around the midpoint as centerpoint)

[image]

And adjust your desired settings.

[image]